# USSD Gateway Connection

Tags: java, gateway, ussd

need help regarding USSD Gateway.

I have to develop an app, which will directly connect to telco's USSD Gateway and listen messages on specific allocated short code number e.g. 444.

Actually, when a customer issue *444# USSD from his phone, request arrived at teleco's USSD Gateway, and it should forward to my app, which should be connected and listening mode. It process the request and give back the response. FYI, I have credentials from telco to connect with their USSD Gateway.

Anybody, can give me idea/help/concept how I can achieve this, in Java.

This is taking my head and I will be bungle of thankful for the person who help me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Solution]**
Yes, we received USSDC Gateway specification, and they are totally different than SMPP specification.

So, we just developed TCP based program which assemble the packet in desired format and sent them to the USSDC gateway, the response is parsed as USSDC docs said.

That's how we make the communication possible.

We used Apache Mina for optimal & Java NIO for socket communication, threads & polling and stuff like that. Over Apache Mina, we just send / receive our PDU/Packets.

Comment: Just build your string or bytes with required format, build header and add packet length bytes and send the packet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how their ussd gateway supports communication .. i.e if it is smpp then you need smpp protocol implementation to connect to their gateway. process the request and give response back.. just like sms.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. This is true for which USSDC fully complaint with SMPP protocol specs.